# Alternating Link crossings.

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Consider a link consisting of $2n$ components such that each components passes over or under each other component exactly $2$ times. Prove that you can swap any of the crossings any number of times so that the link becomes alternating.

Can someone help? I'm not sure where to start.

I think the way to solve this is to prove such an alternating link exists that satisfies the conditions and from there show a way to make that alternating link just by swapping crossings. I'm not sure how to continue from here unfortunately.

I'm mainly looking for an algorithm that would transform the link into an alternating one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: My apologies Mr. Santos. I think the way to solve this is to prove such an alternating link exists that satisfies the conditions and from there show a way to make that alternating link just by swapping crossings. I'm not sure how to continue from here unfortunately.

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of posting that as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show alternating projections exist for any link, first take a planar doodle where all link crossings are transverse double points. Step 1 is to show that such a doodle can be $2$-colored. [To see this, define a coloring function by drawing a line from a region out to infinity that intersects the doodle in finitely many double points. The parity of the number of intersections gives you a $2$-coloring. The fact that any two lines give the same parity is a consequence of the Jordan separation theorem.]
 Now fix a $2$-coloring of the doodle. So all crossings have an alternating white and shaded pattern as you move around them. Now, as you approach each crossing insist that the strand coming in from your right is an over-crossing.  Verify that this is independent of which of the two shaded regions you approach from. Then also verify that this gives an alternating diagram.

In the picture below, I illustrate how to turn an intersection into a crossing using the coloring data. The second picture illustrates how two adjacent crossings going around a shaded region are forced to alternate.

[image]

I first learned this argument in Louis Kauffman's book "On Knots."

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After testing your procedure on a few link diagrams, I can confirm that it indeed works. Could you please explain a bit more details on why this works and how on the diagram being $2$-colored as anything to do with this?

Comment: @goodmath1234: The statement is false on most surfaces. For example, if you put a planar doodle on a torus, you can't necessarily find an alternating diagram for it. This is related to the fact that the mod $2$ intersection of any two transverse curves in the plane is zero (which is where my $2$-coloring came from), whereas this is not the case on the torus.

Comment: Also, note my argument proves the more general statement for any link diagram, not just ones where the pairwise intersection of components is $2$.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that the link diagram lies on a flat plane. I'm new to knot theory so I'm not sure what you mean by the mod $2$ intersection of any transverse curve. How do I use the $2$ coloring to pick which strand is the over strand?

Comment: @goodmath1234: put yourself in one of the shaded regions and approach an intersection. Then make the strand on your right an over crossing.

Comment: I see thank you! Do you have a link to a proof on why this works?

Comment: I gave a sketch of the proof. You just have to verify that crossings that are next to each other alternate. I'll post a picture.